# Android 6.0 closing app after requesting permissions causes permissions to be asked for 3 times each

Tags: android, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I ran into a strange bug (I think) when trying to update my app to use Android 6.0 permissions. My code is as follows:

```
public void requestPerms2() 
    boolean gratedPermissions = false;
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();

    int hasPerm1 = PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED; //Assume granted on low level
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 15) {
        hasPerm1 = pm.checkPermission(
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                this.getPackageName());
    }
    int hasPerm2 = pm.checkPermission(
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
            this.getPackageName());

    if(hasPerm1 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        String [] neededPerms = {some.path.here.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, neededPerms , 1);
        gratedPermissions = true;
    }

    if(hasPerm2 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        String [] neededPerms = {some.path.here.Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO};
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, neededPerms , 1);
        grantedPermissions = true;
    }
    if(grantedPermissions)
        System.exit(0);
}
```

This is inside a method called from onCreate, and is definitely called only one time (I have some debug statements I took out). However, it will prompt the user for permissions 3 times each. I've tried varying the requested permissions, and it always asks 3 times each. If I comment out the System.exit(0), it works perfectly and asks the user one time per permission.

I ideally want to close the app after getting permissions and forcing a relaunch, since the permissions won't apply until after an app restart. Is there any way to do this without asking the user to allow permissions 3 times each?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using [ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#checkSelfPermission(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String))? There's no version checking required there.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't collate your `requestPermissions()` together if you need both permissions? It takes an array of permissions on purpose

Comment: I had tried both of those and got the same results (it would request both permissions at once 3 times while using collated requestPermissions). I didn't want to use an array in this case so that if only one permission was denied by the user, they would just be asked for that one (maybe requestPermissions() handles this automatically?)

Answer (score 1):

I would just put this as a comment but Im not reputable enough yet :(
Android will automatically restart your app and call onCreate if the permission you are requesting requires a restart. You can then use the callback:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults){
    if(requestCode == 101)
    {
        if( (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) || (grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to get permissions for ...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

then check whether the appropriate permission has been granted.
This would negate the need to exit the app altogether.